# Why can't dependent types in Idris handle this situation?

Tags: idris

I want to do the following:

```
data Foo : (a : Type) -> (b : Type) -> (c : a -> b -> Type) -> Type where
  Bar : a -> (c a) -> Foo a b c
```

but I get the following error:

```
When checking type of test.Bar:
When checking argument c to test.Foo:
    Type mismatch between
            Type -> Type (Type of c)
    and
            a -> b -> Type (Expected type)

    Specifically:
            Type mismatch between
                    Type
            and
                    b -> Type
```

This seems like it should be valid to me.  That is `c` has the correct type in the expression `Foo a b c`, but Idris thinks it has the type `b -> Type`, or what I think of as `(c a)`.

Am I missing something, or is this a limitation of Idris?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(c a)` has type `b -> Type`, while all fields of a data constructor must have type `Type`. It's an error, exactly as Idris says. Your `c` type constructor takes two arguments but you only applied it to a single `a`.

Comment: A bit of a nitpick, but `(c a)` should have the type `b -> Type` (since `b : Type` and `c : a -> b -> Type`).